# Oracle sql one-to-many Join

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm new to this sql world. After I'm a developer with limited knowledge in SQL & simple joins. I have an issue in writing sql join for one-to-many relationship. Here's my problem say -

**For instance** if I have a VendorsList table with:

```
id   Name         address
1    sales        Japan
2    marketing    US
```

And a VendorContacts table with:

```
id   vendorid        vendorempname
1    1               Tom
2    1               Bill
3    2               Jessy
4    1               Rachel
5    2               Rob
```

Now what I want after join is :

```
vendor_id    Name     address   vendorempname
1            Sales    Japan     Tom
1            Sales    Japan     Bill
1            Sales    Japan     Rachel
2            Marketing US       Jessy
2            Marketing US       Rob
```

Can any one help in writing join for this please?

Answer (score 3):

This should do the work

```
Select v.vendor_id, v.name, v.address, vc.vendorempname
  from VendorContacts vc
  join VendorList v
    on v.id = vc.vendor_id
 order by vc.vendor_id
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  SELECT b.vendor_id, a.Name, a.address, b.vendorempname
    FROM VendorList a, VendorContact b
   WHERE a.id = b.vendor_id
ORDER BY b.vendor_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

Please have look this:

```
Select vl.vendorId,vl.name,vl.address,vc.vendorempname
from vendorlist as vl
right join VendorContacts as vc
on vl.vendorId = vc.vendorId
order by vc.vendorId asc
```

please try this and will get data that you want.

Answer (score 0):

Try below query. It gives the exact results you are looking for except the order of the reps name..

```
            WITH VENDORLIST AS 
            (SELECT '1' ID,    'sales' Name,      'Japan'  address FROM DUAL
            UNION
            SELECT '2' ID,    'marketing' Name,      'US'  address FROM DUAL),
            VENDORCONTACTS AS 
            (
            SELECT '1' ID,    '1' vendorid,      'Tom'  vendorempname FROM DUAL
            UNION
            SELECT '2' ID,    '1' vendorid,      'Bill'  vendorempname FROM DUAL
            UNION
            SELECT '3' ID,    '2' vendorid,      'Jessy'  vendorempname FROM DUAL
            UNION
            SELECT '4' ID,    '1' vendorid,      'Rachel'  vendorempname FROM DUAL
            UNION
            SELECT '5' ID,    '2' vendorid,      'Rob'  vendorempname FROM DUAL

            )
            SELECT VENDORID, NAME, ADDRESS, vendorempname FROM VENDORLIST, VENDORCONTACTS
            WHERE VENDORCONTACTS.vendorid = VENDORLIST.ID
            ORDER BY VENDORID, NAME, ADDRESS, vendorempname
            ;
```